# In Elixir REPL iex, how do I suppress long pattern matching results

Tags: elixir

In the Elixir repl, iex, when I do an assignment I get the result of the pattern match printed in yellow:

[image]

This is great until the pattern match is long, for example a file:

[image]

...and obviously if it's a large file it a) takes forever (not because of the read time, but to prep for printing the pattern match to screen), and then b) it scrolls for ages.

How can I suppress this behaviour, or limit the size of the pattern matching output?

Comment: You can try with `File.stream!/3` http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/File.html#stream!/3.There're options `line` or `byte` you want to match

Comment: Okay, then how do I run the entire stream? If I type f = File.stream!("msgfile.txt", [], 1) ]> Stream.run then all it does is give me :ok.

Comment: How exactly do you want to limit the size of the pattern matching output? can i have an example?

Comment: Well, I have a large file, and I want to bring the whole thing into a variable. You're suggesting using File.stream! but I don't know how to "run" the entire Stream... can this be done? Or must I use Enum.take? Because with Enum.take I need to know how long the stream is which defeats the purpose. Basically I want to go through the entire file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How Elixir REPL prints your terms

Elixir REPL by default limits the length of an output to be printed:

```
iex(16)> Enum.to_list(1..100)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
```

You can change that by using the `Kernel.inspect/2` function with the `:limit` option. For example, `Kernel.inspect Enum.to_list(1..100), limit: :infinity`will print the whole list.

However, the `:limit` option does not apply to strings nor charlists and `File.read/1` returns a string (UTF-8 encoded binary). But you can still limit the output printed by telling the `inspect/2` to treat your string as normal sequence of bytes (just binary):

`Kernel.inspect File.read!("a.txt"), limit: 60, binaries: :as_binaries`

### Going through the entire file with streams

To perform an operation on each line of your file, you could use `Enum.each/2` over a Stream and pass it appropriate function:

`File.stream!("a.txt") |> Enum.each fn line -> IO.puts line end`

This code will simply print each line.

Comment: Very comprehensive, but this becomes very verbose every time, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly but if you're asking whether Kernel.inspect/2 becomes very verbose every time then the answer is *no* because you can tell it to print 0 items in a given term by using the [limit option](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html). But it *does" become very verbose every time when printing binaries as strings and char lists as char lists (i.e. displaying the printable characters).

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is if this behaviour can be made to become the default, or if I have to type this long string out every time.

Comment: You can use `IEx.configure/1` to set it per IEx session or permanently through the `~/.iex.exs` file. See [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) for more details.

Comment: okay I got this working. So the line is IEx.configure(inspect: [binaries: :as_binaries]) and from there forward it will treat strings as binaries and apply the usual limit on them. This works well and is a good solution I think, even if you then have a slightly less intuitive list of numbers instead of the strings.

Comment: For @mentels 's above comment, information on `IEx.configure/1` and `.iex.exs` is now on hexdocs over [here](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.5/IEx.html#module-configuring-the-shell).

Answer (score 9):

I just add another statement (`; 0` is a nice short one) to the end of the expression for this which makes `iex` not print the output of the first expression, and only the last one:

```
iex(1)> a = Enum.to_list(1..100); 0
0
iex(2)> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

While @dogbert's answer is the simplest solution, there's another interesting way of suppressing IEx output provided by `IEx` itself. Just call this function at the end:

```
IEx.dont_display_result
```

---

So, you can do this in IEx:

```
f = File.read!(my_large_file); IEx.dont_display_result
```